# Roommate/co-tenant said she would renew but lied after I sign lease - invalid lease?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, real-estate, residential-lease, lease

So, my roommates and I planned to sign a lease renewal as co-tenants in NYC. While some of the roommates already signed it, the others changed their mind last minute. This unfortunately means the tenants that did sign must cover the costs of the open rooms, which we're struggling to do because we were under the impression that all the original tenants would stay and split the apartment costs. So we regret signing the renewal.

However, the lease addressed the names of all the original tenants. So if some parties leave their signature fields empty, does that make the lease incomplete and valid/void for everyone?

Comment: Voiding of the lease and making it binding even to those who did not sign it are both very unlikely, although one would need to know the terms of the lease in order to make a precise assessment. You might want to elaborate on, or preferably reproduce, the key portions of the lease. Also, does the lease mention anything in the sense of tenants being "jointly and severally liable"? If so, that would further reduce the signers' chances of voiding that contract.

Comment: This is a nasty situation that may leave you on the hook for a  lot of money. I recommend contacting NYC HRA which offers legal advice to tenants and reaching out to any other tenants union, law clinic, or tenant rights group that you can find. https://www1.nyc.gov/site/hra/help/legal-services-for-tenants.page